# Hypergeometric ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

$$ r^2 u′′+r(a+bn r^s)u′+(c+d r^s)u=0$$
How does one convert this equation into the Whittaker equation?

Comment: A duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4399274). Were you able to find $a_2, b_2, c_2, d_2$?

Comment: @Maxim That original linked question is closed and downvoted, so maybe this duplicate is better?

Comment: i don't know whether it is duplicate or not .any one know how to i can convert this above question

Comment: can any one helping me out ??